# Displaying Webpages From RSS Feed in iOS Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webview, rss, formatting

Currently, I have an RSS Feed Reader in a UITableView within a Navigation Control. I would like to click on the links and Open up a formatted page (containing all of the information from the website formatted for the iOS screen). I'm not sure if I should do this using the RSS data and a UITextView? I'm currently attempting to use UITextView in hopes that I can separate the information (title, author, body) without anything looking promising. I want to be able to move around the data and format it to my liking in the actual application itself. I read around and noted that you can include HTML and custom CSS. Would this be the way to go? I'm not quite sure how to tackle this. I want the page that opens up to be entirely scrollable (Like the IGN application or Slashgear application). Many apps for websites utilize this (and I am a bit new to this). How do they go about this? I also want to note, at some point I will like to cache the data so it may load what is already loaded without being connected to the internet. Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit:
Ok, I believe I found the correct path to go down from playing around and a lot of googling (nothing directly says what a decent way of doing this is). My particular way as of now is the route of a UIScrollView in general. Now the part I don't understand is how to divide up the long text into 'pages' for scrolling (and I am using the paging feature. This situation has led me into this question: [How To Separate Strings For UIScrollView/UITextView based on the size of the frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021253/how-to-separate-strings-for-uiscrollview-uitextview-based-on-the-size-of-the-fra)

Comment: have you used textView for displaying information??

Comment: If you read the linked thread, I ended up using a scroll view with a uitextview in it. I'm still debating on whether I should have used a uiwebview instead though.

Comment: yeah man ,,just use webview. i also had similar problem. try to use it like below.                                                [rssWeb loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='text-align:justify; font-size:30px;font-family:HelveticaNeue;color:#5d5757;'>%@</div>",getwebString] baseURL:nil];

Comment: I didn't realize you could toss in everything like that for formatting. That's where my confusion was with the webview side. First I wanted to know if I could toss in my own CSS sheet.. (which I kinda got an answer to but not really).. and then creating a string to pass to the webview with the content seemed too simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe I found the correct path to go down from playing around and a lot of googling (nothing directly says what a decent way of doing this is). My particular way as of now is the route of a UIScrollView in general. Now the part I don't understand is how to divide up the long text into 'pages' for scrolling (and I am using the paging feature. This situation has led me into this question: [How To Separate Strings For UIScrollView/UITextView based on the size of the frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021253/how-to-separate-strings-for-uiscrollview-uitextview-based-on-the-size-of-the-fra)